# Converting table data to vertical list in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets

Could anybody help with a way to convert a table of data into a vertical list in Excel?

I've tried to use a macro, but it keeps tripping up and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

I'm downloading a large table of data, but that data then needs to be put in a list for another macro on the sheet to work. With how much data there is, it's impractical to do it manually, so I'm wondering if there's a quick way round it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you know macro then then try to count the data range and use it for transpose.

Comment: How many columns of data do you have in the sheet? Can you show what the sheet looks like?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in a single formula. Assume you have a spreadsheet which looks like this (I have put in dummy data showing the position of the cell, so you can see where it ends up):

[image: Spreadsheet with 8 columns and 15 rows]

In another cell (or another sheet) put the following formula:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/8),(COLUMN(A:A)-1)+MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,8))
```

The two 8's in the formula are there because the sheet has 8 columns, if it had more or less you would change these 8's to the number of columns your spreadsheet has.

Then you copy the formula down and you get this:

[image: Sheet with formula in]

It works because it uses the offset formula, which gets the contents of a cell using a row and column reference.

```
INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/8)
```

This part makes sure the row count does not move on from 1 to 2 etc until 8 rows of the new formula have been created, making room for the 8 columns to be copied.

```
(COLUMN(A:A)-1)+MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,8)
```

This part takes the column and adds on 1 for each row down we go, until we reach column 8 when the MOD function returns to 0 and we start a new row of data on the original sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Something liek this should do the trick for ya.

```
Sub TransposeThis()

Set Rng = Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2:B6")   'Input range of all fruits
Set Rng_output = Sheets("sheet2").Range("B2")   'Output range

For i = 1 To Rng.Cells.Count
    Set rng_values = Range(Rng.Cells(i).Offset(0, 1), Rng.Cells(i).End(xlToRight)) 'For each fruit taking the values to the right which need to be transposed

    If rng_values.Cells.Count < 16000 Then 'To ensure that it doesnt select till the right end of the sheet
        For j = 1 To rng_values.Cells.Count
                Rng_output.Value = Rng.Cells(i).Value
                Rng_output.Offset(0, 1).Value = rng_values.Cells(j).Value
                Set Rng_output = Rng_output.Offset(1, 0)  'Shifting the output row so that next value can be printed
        Next j
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Or, if you just want to transpose everything into one single vector, which sounds a bit weird, but there may be a need for such a thing, you can try the script below.

```
Sub TryThis()
  Dim rRow          As Range
  Dim nCol          As Long
  Dim iOfs          As Long

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  With Sheet1.Range("A1:E20")
    nCol = .Columns.Count
    For Each rRow In .Rows
      rRow.Copy
      Sheet2.Range("A2").Offset(iOfs).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
      iOfs = iOfs + nCol
    Next rRow
  End With
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```